# How to create a hard link when installing an application in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have two applications that share a lot of code. Creating a shared library is a bit of overkill though. So I'd like to have a single executable hard linked to two executable names and then, depending on the name in argv[0], decide which main to use. May sound exotic, but is not that unusual.

Now the point is, how do I create the hard link at install time? I tried something like this:

```
add_excutable(foo ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.cpp)
install(TARGETS foo RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR})
install(CODE "file(CREATE_LINK ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR}/foo ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR}/bar)")
```

The last line is executed at install time, but BIN_INSTALL_DIR does not seem to be defined in the last line resulting in the error that /foo could not be found. Duh.

Of course, there are many ways to do this differently, like simply creating two applications. But I hope I overlooked a simple way to achieve what I intended in the first place.